# Datatables button extension with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i have problem load datatable library using require js
this is my code

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery" :    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min",
        "datatables" : "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min",
        "datatables-btn" : "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min",
    }
});


requirejs( ["datatables", "datatables-btn"], function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
});
```

and i got this error on development console 
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EVWy.png)

thanks for your help..

Comment: is this a case of a missing file?

Comment: yes sir, i dont know why need datatables.net,js
if i remove "datatables-btn" form requirejs, no problem found, but i need datatables button extension

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a lot of `.js` script files. The easiest way to find out what script files you need is to go to the [DataTables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index) (even if you aren't downloading) and pick out what extensions/features you need. This will generate a list of script files (for download or CDN) you need to include, which you can then convert to the RequireJS syntax to include. I put together a list of what it seems like you will need and here it is:

```
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"
"https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"
"https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"
"https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"
```

You may think that this is too many, or that I've added unneccessary scripts, but let me explain the additions.

- jszip is necessary if you want your excel export button to work (this is documented on DataTables download page)
- pdfmake is necessary for the pdf export button to work
- vfs_fonts is also part of pdfmake
- you need the two buttons.html5 script files for your buttons to work correctly (assuming you want to use HTML5 buttons, if you want to use Flash buttons you'd have to go to the download builder and pick Flash buttons)

These should be all the scripts you need to include (as far as I can tell from your code snippet) but if you want to double-check or even add more features down the line, I'd recommend checking out the link above to find the list of script files you need.